# Nodejs/c++ addon - getting error "undefined symbol: speech_config_from_subscription" from Microsoft speech SDK on ubuntu 18.4 server

Tags: c++, node.js, gstreamer, speech-to-text, mu-law

Actually, I want to do speech transcription with passing MULAW (g711) audio format to microsoft-speech-sdk (Nodejs), but MULAW streaming audio format is not supported to microsoft-speech-sdk (Nodejs).
So, for this required GStreamer with C++.

So, I'm going to create node/c++ addon for this. but I am facing below error.

```
1|server  | node /home/*****Transation/server.js: symbol lookup error: /home/*****Transation/stream-translation/cpp_asr/build/Release/accumulate.node: undefined symbol: speech_config_from_subscription
```

Installed the Speech SDK using [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/quickstarts/setup-platform?pivots=programming-language-cpp&tabs=linux%2Cubuntu%2Cdotnet%2Cjre%2Cmaven%2Cnodejs%2Cmac%2Cpypi).

Using reference for addon [link](https://github.com/freezer333/streaming-worker/blob/master/examples/accumulate/accumulate.cpp).

Comment: Hey did you get this working? I also need node.js bindings for the C++ Speech SDK for offline wake word detection which isn't implemented in the JS SDK. Saw this and was hoping maybe you could share since you did it already? 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution, Just coped this `libMicrosoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.core.so` library into `/usr/lib` folder and modified `binding.gyp` file. it is working fine.

```json
{
  "targets": [
    {
      "target_name": "transcription",
      "sources": ["src/streamingAsr.cpp"],
      "cflags": ["-Wall", "-std=c++17"],
      "cflags!": ["-fno-exceptions"],
      "cflags_cc!": ["-fno-exceptions"],
      "include_dirs": [
        "/home/delaplexTransation/speechsdk/include/cxx_api",
        "/home/delaplexTransation/speechsdk/include/c_api",
        "<!(node -e \"require('nan')\")",
        "<!(node -e \"require('streaming-worker-sdk')\")"
      ],
      "libraries": [
        "/usr/lib/libMicrosoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.core.so"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```